# How to read a file synchronisly from the web with node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm using node.js to build a webapp and I need to use synchronous request for getting a file.

I know how to get the file locally:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var myFile = fs.readFileSync('myFile.html', 'utf8');
```

but I want to read this file from the web like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var myFile = fs.readFileFromWebSync('http://www.theweb.com/myFile.html', 'utf8');
```

**How do I read a file synchroniously from web?**

I need it to be synchronious because this is part of a single build process and not part of a web server.

Comment: Using asynchronous calls is not relevant only when building web servers. You really should use them also in your case, because it will save your CPUs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the filesystem tools to read from an URL. You should use [this](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library

As one can see in the example you should do the following:

```
request('http://www.theweb.com/myFile.html').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myFile.html'))
```

This would read from the provided URL into the pointed file on your filesystem. You will find on the [page](https://github.com/mikeal/request) of the library multiple examples.

Comment: Though it seems like a nice solution. The file that it creates is empty.

Comment: @Alon currently I don't have a system running node at hand to try it also. I would recommend publishing the content retrieved using the log. I would try it again later. Thank you

Comment: @Alon - just tried the same line I posted for you in the node console-> it works like a charm, please let me know if I can help you with something

Comment: sorry for the late response. it worked like a charm. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can use `require('child_process').execSync('curl http://www.theweb.com/myFile.html')` in current master (v0.11.11).

But you'd better have really good reason for doing that.